# How do I know all the objects in my entity framework model programatically

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to find out if there is a way we can iterate over all the objects in my entity framework model? I tried looking through intellisense and msdn and stackoverflow but couldn't properly identify anything that matched my query.

Something like the following ...

```
foreach(var item in entities.Context.getAllObjects())
{
    Console.Write(item.Name);
}
```

The point of this is that I want to be able to write some reports over database objects for our developers and devops teams to better understand what's happening in our production servers. I've already got the data into the tables in a separate database that I want to report on. But instead of writing the specific reports that we may or may not want to see. I'd like to be able to provide some sort of interface that might list the possible report tables. Then have some options that might be group by date, dayOfWeek or Hour from this date to this date.

I don't want there to have to be application changes in order to add new reports. This is my first hurdle in writing this app ... I'm sure there'll be others. Because the application is for our development team I'm not going to worry about someone trying to query the data in a way that doesn't make sense ... and I also want there to be an absolute minimum barrier to entry as we can't write a report for everything that we want to track.

Thanks

Comment: You need reflection.  This will not be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
var typesInYourContext = context.GetType()
   .GetProperties()
   .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(DbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
   .Select(p=>p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
```

(I havent compiled it and its off the top of my head but it should give you the general idea)

Note: EF may actually pull in more types than those listed in your context, but this will only get the ones you explicitly list in the DbContext.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try ... I'm not currently using code first, so I'll if I can make that work for an objectcontext ... I'll try it out tomorrow and get back to you ...

Comment: @KevinDonde ahh right yeah you will need to change the thing you are looking for when you use objectcontext. Should be a pretty similar principal though, reflect collections on the context and grab their generic types